# Do default values for optional parameters have to be static?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some functionality that I could implement using method overloading/chaining but I'm wondering if I can achieve the same functionality with optional parameters. Here is an example of what I would to like achieve, below it is a version with method chaining (hopefully that will make my intent clear). Can this be done using optional parameters?

```
// what I would like to do
private string CreateMessageFromTemplate(string templateId, Contact contact, string email = contact.emails.FirstOrDefault()) { ... }

//what I know I can do    
private string CreateMessageFromTemplate(string templateId, Contact contact)
{
     CreateMessageFromTemplate(templateId, contact, contact.emails.FirstOrDefault());
}

private string CreateMessageFromTemplate(string templateId, Contact contact, string email) { ... }
```

As you can see, I derive the default value from the contact argument (if you don't give me a specific email, I'll just use the first one in the list). Do the default values of optional parameters have to be static or can they be the result of an expression like in my example? If they can, what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default value for an argument has to be a compile-time constant.  What you can do though, is make the default null, and then set it in the function:

```
private string CreateMessageFromTemplate(string templateId, Contact contact, string email = null)
{
    email = email ?? contact.emails.FirstOrDefault()) 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: I should have known that... As soon as I read your answer I remembered seeing this in C# In Depth. Accepting when the cooldown ends.